# Truncate before inserting data to mysql with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, truncate

I'm trying to upload an excel file to a mysql DB using PHP. I've got this working.
However, if I refresh the page or upload again another file, it gets duplicated.

I would like before it uploads a new file to clear (truncate) the table and then insert the new data.

Bue I cannot find where to put or how to put the `TRUNCATE TABLE existencias_2018;` if the Submit button is clicked and before it inserts the data.

Another issue is the refreshing thing. It is a way to stop the refresh after I've uploaded the data? Or a way that refreshing doesn't duplicate it?

So in summary the help i need is:

- Where to put and how the `TRUNCATE TABLE existencias_2018;`.
- Stop duplicating data if page gets refreshed.

Here is my piece of code:

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","papa");
require_once('vendor/php-excel-reader/excel_reader2.php');
require_once('vendor/SpreadsheetReader.php');

if (isset($_POST["import"])){
    $allowedFileType = ['application/vnd.ms-excel','text/xls','text/xlsx','application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'];
    if(in_array($_FILES["file"]["type"],$allowedFileType)){
        $targetPath = 'uploads/'.$_FILES['file']['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetPath);
        $Reader = new SpreadsheetReader($targetPath);
        $sheetCount = count($Reader->sheets());
        for($i=0;$i<$sheetCount;$i++){
            $Reader->ChangeSheet($i);
            foreach ($Reader as $Row){
                $model = "";
                if(isset($Row[0])) {
                    $model = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Row[0]);
                }
                $cup = "";
                if(isset($Row[1])) {
                    $cup = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Row[1]);
                }
                $color = "";
                if(isset($Row[1])) {
                    $color = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Row[2]);
                }
                $description = "";
                if(isset($Row[1])) {
                    $description = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Row[3]);
                }
                $size36 = "";
                if(isset($Row[1])) {
                    $size36 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Row[4]);
                }
                $size38 = "";
                if(isset($Row[1])) {
                    $size38 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Row[5]);
                }
                $size40 = "";
                if(isset($Row[1])) {
                    $size40 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Row[6]);
                }
                $size42 = "";
                if(isset($Row[1])) {
                    $size42 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Row[7]);
                }
                $size44 = "";
                if(isset($Row[1])) {
                    $size44 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Row[8]);
                }
                $size46 = "";
                if(isset($Row[1])) {
                    $size46 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Row[9]);
                }
                $size48 = "";
                if(isset($Row[1])) {
                    $size48 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Row[10]);
                }
                $size50 = "";
                if(isset($Row[1])) {
                    $size50 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Row[11]);
                }
                $size52 = "";
                if(isset($Row[1])) {
                    $size52 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Row[12]);
                }
                $size54 = "";
                if(isset($Row[1])) {
                    $size54 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Row[13]);
                }
                if (!empty($model) || !empty($cup) || !empty($color) || !empty($description) || !empty($size36) || !empty($size38) || !empty($size40) || !empty($size42) || !empty($size44) || !empty($size46) || !empty($size48) || !empty($size50) || !empty($size52) || !empty($size54)) {
                    $query = "insert into existencias_2018(model,cup,color,description,size36,size38,size40,size42,size44,size46,size48,size50,size52,size54) values('".$model."','".$cup."','".$color."','".$description."','".$size36."','".$size38."','".$size40."','".$size42."','".$size44."','".$size46."','".$size48."','".$size50."','".$size52."','".$size54."')";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                    if (! empty($result)) {
                        $type = "success";
                        $message = "Datos de Excel importados en la base de datos satisfactoriamente";
                    } else {
                        $type = "error";
                        $message = "Ha habido un problema al importar los datos de Excel";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }else{ 
        $type = "error";
        $message = "Tipo de archivo invalido. Suba un archivo de Excel.";
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
    <head>
        <style>    
            body {
                font-family: Arial;
                width: 1000px;
            }
            .outer-container {
                background: #F0F0F0;
                border: #e0dfdf 1px solid;
                padding: 40px 20px;
                border-radius: 2px;
            }
            .btn-submit {
                background: #333;
                border: #1d1d1d 1px solid;
                border-radius: 2px;
                color: #f0f0f0;
                cursor: pointer;
                padding: 5px 20px;
                font-size:0.9em;
            }
            .tutorial-table {
                margin-top: 40px;
                font-size: 0.8em;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                width: 100%;
            }
            .tutorial-table th {
                background: #f0f0f0;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
                padding: 8px;
                text-align: left;
            }
            .tutorial-table td {
                background: #FFF;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
                padding: 8px;
                text-align: left;
            }
            #response {
                padding: 10px;
                margin-top: 10px;
                border-radius: 2px;
                display:none;
            }
            .success {
                background: #c7efd9;
                border: #bbe2cd 1px solid;
            }
            .error {
                background: #fbcfcf;
                border: #f3c6c7 1px solid;
            }
            div#response.display-block {
                display: block;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Importar existencias actualizadas</h2>
        <div class="outer-container">
            <form action="" method="post"
            name="frmExcelImport" id="frmExcelImport" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div>
                    <label>Buscar archivo Excel</label>
                    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept=".xls,.xlsx">
                    <button type="submit" id="submit" name="import" class="btn-submit">Importar</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
       <div id="response" class="<?php if(!empty($type)) { echo $type . " display-block"; } ?>"><?php if(!empty($message)) { echo $message; } ?></div>
<?php
$sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM existencias_2018";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlSelect);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
?>
       <table class='tutorial-table'>
           <thead>
               <tr>
                   <th>Modelo</th>
                   <th>Copa</th>
                   <th>Color</th>
                   <th>Descripcion</th>
                   <th>36</th>
                   <th>38</th>
                   <th>40</th>
                   <th>42</th>
                   <th>44</th>
                   <th>46</th>
                   <th>48</th>
                   <th>50</th>
                   <th>52</th>
                   <th>54</th>
               </tr>
           </thead>
<?php
$sql = "TRUNCATE TABLE existencias_2018";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>                  
           <tbody>
               <tr>
                   <td><?php  echo $row['model']; ?></td>
                   <td><?php  echo $row['cup']; ?></td>
                   <td><?php  echo $row['color']; ?></td>
                   <td><?php  echo $row['description']; ?></td>
                   <td><?php  echo $row['size36']; ?></td>
                   <td><?php  echo $row['size38']; ?></td>
                   <td><?php  echo $row['size40']; ?></td>
                   <td><?php  echo $row['size42']; ?></td>
                   <td><?php  echo $row['size44']; ?></td>
                   <td><?php  echo $row['size46']; ?></td>
                   <td><?php  echo $row['size48']; ?></td>
                   <td><?php  echo $row['size50']; ?></td>
                   <td><?php  echo $row['size52']; ?></td>
                   <td><?php  echo $row['size54']; ?></td>
               </tr>
<?php
}
?>
           </tbody>
       </table>
<?php 
} 
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be simpler to prevent duplicate insertion than truncating the table every time.

Comment: What do you mean, you “can not find it” where to place this? Do you understand what the script you have is doing, at least in broad terms? You only want to do this if the form was submitted, so if should presumably go _inside_ the `if (isset($_POST["import"]))` block. And the records are inserted inside the nested for-foreach loop, so you probably want to do it _before_ that. But of course you will have to _execute_ that statement - just assigning `$sql = "TRUNCATE TABLE existencias_2018";` does not do that, that is just a string value assigned to a variable.

Comment: The thing is that the model number can be repeated couple times and the size data changes constantly. So I cannot check if the data is duplicated or won't be worth it I believe. 
I don't mind removing all the data from the table. Because every time I upload a file the data is different or can be different from what was stored in the DB.
The excel file can vary each month. So I thought it would be much easier to remove everything from the DB before uploading the new file.
The amount of data to manage isn't too big maybe less than 100 entries a year and each year a new table will be created.

Comment: misorude, I'm pretty new with these things. I've spent hours trying to do what I've achieved. I don't understand much, so I'm going pretty slow documenting myself and trying to get help from people that know what they are doing. I'm learning slowly. This is just something for a family member. Nothing too big but needs to be done. And I'm the only one brave enough to try it. So I appreciate the help.

Comment: Well, I don't think the problem about checking is about simplicity, more of integrity. I mean if there is whatever problem between the truncation and the insert you end up with an empty db, so no new data nor old. So, if that's ok with you then it's all right, otherwise you should think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you want ?

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","papa");
require_once('vendor/php-excel-reader/excel_reader2.php');
require_once('vendor/SpreadsheetReader.php');

if (isset($_POST["import"])){
    $allowedFileType = ['application/vnd.ms-excel','text/xls','text/xlsx','application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'];
    if(in_array($_FILES["file"]["type"],$allowedFileType)){

        // Looks like we have a correct file to upload.
        // Let's TRUNCATE the table first :

        $query = "TRUNCATE TABLE existencias_2018;";
        mysqli_query($conn, $query);

       // OK, table is empty, proceed with upload....       

        $targetPath = 'uploads/'.$_FILES['file']['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetPath);
        $Reader = new SpreadsheetReader($targetPath);
        $sheetCount = count($Reader->sheets());
        for($i=0;$i<$sheetCount;$i++){
            $Reader->ChangeSheet($i);
            foreach ($Reader as $Row){
                $model = "";
                if(isset($Row[0])) {
                    $model = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Row[0]);
                }
        // and so on...
```

Comment: That's what I needed. I guess I was too tired and couldn't think much more. Thanks for the help. I really appreciate it.